# How to integrate the Emulator with the Testing Tool?

Tags: iphone, testing, android-emulator

Can somebody suggest me how to integrate the Emulator with the Testing Tool? And any suitable Testing tool name as well which could be connect to any apple or android emulator?

Thanks in Advance.
Vadivelan.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OCUnit, it is integrated into Xcode.  The Uint Test integration is quite good in Xcode 4.x.